# switchMap inside pipe() VS sequence of switchMap

Tags: rxjs

I didn't get if there is a difference between this:

```
Observable.pipe( 
           switchMap((res) => {
             ...
            }),
            switchMap((res) => {
             ...
            })
);
```

and this:

```
Observable.pipe(
            switchMap((res) => {
             ...
            }).pipe(
                 switchMap((res) => {
                 ...
                 }),
            )
  );
```

Can you help me understanding if there is differences in the way data are treated?

Thank you

Comment: The 2nd code block cannot be valid. You can't do `switchMap().pipe()` as switchMap doesn't return an Observable but an OperatorFunction. Did you mean to call switchMap inside the first one ? Like switchMap(() => of(1).pipe(switchMap(...))).

Comment: From my experience: it not only depends onto the switchMap itself - it more or less depends on the operators that are used within a switchMap. Pipe evaluates and calls every operator that is given to it at initialization without an emit. If you have a mapTo for instance inside a switchMap or on the same level of a switchMap it can make a difference. Whereas the same level initializes a variable once (and is not mutated over time) the inside mapTo would be evaluated every time an emit is coming from a switchMap. If you want an example I can post you an "answer" that gives an indication.

Comment: @serrulien thank for you help. Yes, actually I meant what you wrote; my second example was wrong :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As it is written, there is no difference, however if you later want to add further items down the pipe, it might matter. For example `catchError` - In the first case, if you add it at the end of the pipe, then it will catch errors thrown by either step of the pipe, but in the 2nd example, you can put it inside the first pipe, after the inner `switchMap` and it will only catch errors on the inner operation.

Oh I just read @serrulien's comment, and he's right, your 2nd pipe cannot be placed where you placed it, it would have been placed inside the body of the first `switchMap`, e.g.:

```js
Observable.pipe(
  switchMap((res) => {
    return someObservable().pipe(
      switchMap((res) => {
        ...
      })
  })
);
```

As the saying goes, there are many ways to skin a cat.

Answer (score 5):

RxJS#pipe is just function composition flipped. It turns out that (like addition), composition is associative.

---

For addition:
x + (y + z) = (x + y) + z

For composition:
x ∘ (y ∘ z) = (x ∘ y) ∘ z

---

What does this mean? Well, you can sort of think of the pipe function as the parentheses in a math equation.

These are all the same expression, just with parentheses in different places: (and since piped RxJS operators are associative, it doesn't matter where the parentheses are)

```ts
// 1
stream.pipe(
  switchMap(/*...*/),
  concatMap(/*...*/),
  delay(/*...*/),
  toArray()
);

// 2
stream.pipe(
  switchMap(/*...*/),
  concatMap(/*...*/)
).pipe(
  delay(/*...*/),
  toArray()
);

// 3
stream.pipe(
  switchMap(/*...*/)
).pipe(
  concatMap(/*...*/)
).pipe(
  delay(/*...*/)
).pipe(
  toArray()
);
```